# Автоматизация огорода

Tags: java, delphi, usb, железо, микроконтроллеры

Доброго время суток.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, планирую сделать автоматизированное управление (как бы смешно не звучала огорода) т.к живу очень далеко а ездить каждые выходные что то не хочется. т.е

- датчик влажности почвы
- датчик влажности
- автоматический полив не по таймеру, а по влажности почвы.

Подскажите какую плату можно использовать? и контроллеры?
Планируется управление по wifi (или чем то еще но только без проводов)
Программировать планирую на delphi или Java, C# только изучаю.
Желательно детали недорогие если можно посоветовать.
У кого какие предложения?
Я никогда ранее не работал с микроконтроллерами и т.д. Извините за некомпетентность.

Comment: arduino mega возможно сделать управление датчиками по wifi?
И если можно хоть что нибудь дать за основу чтобы начинать не с пустого листа?

Comment: очаровательнывй вопрос)))

Comment: @Djuz да, wifi там тоже можно прицепить. Вообще сам кодинг не сложный, начать с нуля просто. Документации в сети полно, дерзайте!)

Comment: я бы на вашем месте делал на C, т.к. тогда можно сделать автономное оборудование без  суперкомпа на грядке.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/167459/ http://habrahabr.ru/post/195998/ Raspberry Pi позволяет писать на Java.

Answer (score 3):

Культивацией плантации собираетесь заниматься?) Датчики влажности, температуры и прочей электроники можно найти на китайский барахолках, типа http://dx.com

За контроллер берите arduino mega, ибо его разъемов должно хватить почти на всё.

Answer (score 2):

Omron! Есть такая фирма, правда дороговато, но программирование их микроконтроллеров, похоже на построение электрических сетей(в их специальной программе есс-но, CX-Programmer вроде или CX-One)

Comment: он стоит как чугунный мост....

Answer (score 2):

Если управление поливом будет автоматическое, то Atmel+Датчик влажности+исполнительное устройство включения полива. 
Если управление будет on-line, то добавляется огородный ПК с GPRS модемом, программа сбора показаний датчиков на огороде с отправкой данных оператору, программа управления на удаленном ПК, связь между ними можно организовать по технологии socket. 
Чтоб управление было стойкое к метеоусловиям передачу данных между ПК и контроллером на огороде лучше организовать по bluetooth (bluegiga, HC-07 ...).
В общем это комплексный проект. И нужно изучить все его составляющие.

Comment: Что такое Atmel? MARC4 или ARM9 (хотя подозреваю, что речь всёже шла про avr8)

Comment: Да, что-нибудь типа Atmega8/Atmega16

Comment: @yuriybuchinskiy Сколько лет указанным микросхемам?

Comment: Понятия не имею, но работают надежно. И стоят копейки. И найти можно где угодно.

Comment: Ежели меня не подводит зрение при взгляде на Revison History, первый ATMega8-datashit :) вышел в декабре 2001 г.

Comment: И что? Он от этого стал хуже работать? Вам не хватает его возможностей?

Answer (score 1):

Самый имхо простой способ - прикупить нужные сенсоры к Android телефону, написать на Java прожку для телефона через [специальное API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment.html) и вуаля.

Comment: Ну, тогда телефон придётся оставить на огороде, жалко как-то. Нет?

Comment: Телефон все равно будет дешевле, чем все эти сенсоры, системы полива и проч. огород :)

Comment: @Barmaley

     Телефон все равно будет дешевле, чем все эти сенсоры, системы полива и проч. огород :)

     Самый имхо простой способ - прикупить нужные сенсоры к Android телефону, написать на Java прожку для телефона через специальное API и вуаля.

Так сенсоры/системы полива нужны или нет? Или достаточно телефона и бабушки?